# How to write sql for zend 3?

Tags: sql, zend-framework

How to write sql for zend 3?

I can not do it.

```
select email as publihser_email, phone_number as publisher_phone_number, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as publisher_name
from users
where id in(
      select distinct publisher_id from apartments where publisher_type=0
    )
UNION
select email as publihser_email, phone_number as publisher_phone_number, name as publisher_name
from organizations
where id in(
      select distinct publisher_id from apartments where publisher_type=1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_wherein2 = new Select('apartments');
$select_wherein2
    ->quantifier(Select::QUANTIFIER_DISTINCT)
    ->columns(['publisher_id'])
    ->where(['publisher_type' => 1]);

$select2 = new Select('organizations');
$select2
    ->columns([
        'publihser_email'           =>  'email',
        'publisher_phone_number'    =>  'phone_number',
        'publisher_name'            =>   'name'])
    ->where->in('id',$select_wherein2);


$select_wherein = new Select('apartments');
$select_wherein
    ->quantifier(Select::QUANTIFIER_DISTINCT)
    ->columns(['publisher_id'])
    ->where(['publisher_type' => 0]);



$select = new Select('users');
$select
    ->columns([
        'publihser_email'           =>  'email',
        'publisher_phone_number'    =>  'phone_number',
        'publisher_name'            =>   new Expression("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)")])
    ->where
    ->in('id',$select_wherein);
$select->combine($select2);

//TEST
echo $select->getSqlString($db->getPlatform());
```

RESULT:

```
( SELECT `users`.`email` AS `publihser_email`, `users`.`phone_number` AS `publisher_phone_number`, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS `publisher_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `apartments`.`publisher_id` AS `publisher_id` FROM `apartments` WHERE `publisher_type` = '0') ) UNION ( SELECT `organizations`.`email` AS `publihser_email`, `organizations`.`phone_number` AS `publisher_phone_number`, `organizations`.`name` AS `publisher_name` FROM `organizations` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `apartments`.`publisher_id` AS `publisher_id` FROM `apartments` WHERE `publisher_type` = '1') )
```